# Regex matching multiple inputs

Tags: regex

I am trying to do a smart input field for UK style weight input, e.g. "6 stone and 3 lb" or "6 st 11 pound", capturing the 2 numbers in groups.

For now I got: `([0-9]{1,2}).*?([0-9]{1,2}).*`

Problem is it matches "12 stone" in 2 groups, 1 and 2 instead of just 12. Is it possible to make a regex which captures correctly in both cases?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the first part possessive so it never gets backtracked into.

```
([0-9]{1,2}+).*?([0-9]{1,2})
```

Comment: +1 for the possessive quantifier, but the OP didn't tell the language, sadly not all languages does support possessive quantifiers

Comment: @stema: in that case you may want to try [atomic grouping](http://www.regular-expressions.info/atomic.html).

Comment: Both atomic groups and possessive quantifiers are not supported in Javascript and Python.

Answer (score 2):

Because . matches everythig including numbers.. try this:

```
/(\d{1,2})\D+(\d{1,2})?/
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
\b(\d+)\b.*?\b(\d+)\b
```

Groups 1 and 2 will have your numbers in either case.

**Explanation :**

```
"
\b       # Assert position at a word boundary
(        # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   \d       # Match a single digit 0..9
      +        # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\b       # Assert position at a word boundary
.        # Match any single character that is not a line break character
   *?       # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
\b       # Assert position at a word boundary
(        # Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   \d       # Match a single digit 0..9
      +        # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\b       # Assert position at a word boundary
"
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, then look at capture groups 1 and 3:
([0-9]{1,2})[^0-9]+(([0-9]{1,2})?.+)?

The idea is to make a number and text manditory, but make a second number and text optional.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion for a regex to match both variants you showed:

```
(?<stone>\d+\s(?:stone|st))(?:\s(and)?\s?)(?<pound>\d+\s(?:pound|lb))
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit vague at the moment, this works:

```
/([0-9]{1,2})(?:[^0-9]+([0-9]{1,2}).*)?/
```

for this data:

6 stone and 3 lb
6 st 11 pound
12 stone
12 st and 11lbs

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as everyone is having a go, here's mine:

```
(\d+)(?:\D+(\d+)?)
```

It's definitely the concisest so far. This will match one or two groups of digits anywhere:

```
"12": ("12", null)
"12st": ("12", null)
"12 st": ("12", null)
"12st 34 lb": ("12", "34")
"cabbage 12st 34 lb": ("12", "34")
"12 potato 34 moo": ("12", "34")
```

The next step would be making it catch the name of the units that were used.

Edit: as pointed out above, we don's know what language you're using, and not all regex functionality is available in all implementations. However as far as I know, \d for digits and \D for non-digits is fairly universal.